# Asp.net mvc without entity framework foreign key relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables Posts(ID,Title,DateTime,Body) & Tags(Id,Name) (and PostsTags(PostID,TagID)) and c# classes:
PostModel.cs:

```
public class PostModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public List<TagModel> Tags { get; set; }
    public List<CommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
    public List<LikeModel> Likes { get; set; }
}
```

TagModel.cs:

```
public class TagModel
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to list all the Posts which has a particular tag name lets say 'even'
So what I do is first get TagID of even

```
query = "SELECT ID FROM Tags where [Name]='" + tagName + "'";
```

and then get posts which has that tag

```
int tagId = int.Parse(dtTag.Rows[0][0].ToString());
query = "select [ID],[Title],[DateTime],[Body] from Posts inner join PostsTag on ID = PostID AND TagID =" + tagId;
```

and now in nested foreach loops I start populating Post but the problem is 
I fill Post and its tags -> I will have to fill posts in tag class -> I will have to will tags in post class -> I will have to fill posts in tag class and so on.
And If I dont I get null reference. So how to alter my c# classes to make this work?

```
foreach (DataRow row1 in dtTag.Rows)
{
    PostModel post = new PostModel();
    post.Body = row1["Body"].ToString();
    post.ID = int.Parse(row1["ID"].ToString());
    post.DateTime = (DateTime)row1["DateTime"];
    post.Title = row1["Title"].ToString();
    int id1 = post.ID;
    query = "SELECT [ID],[Name] FROM Tags as T inner join PostsTag as P on p.TagID=T.ID AND p.PostID=" + id1;
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlCon);
    dtTag.Clear();
    da.Fill(dtTag);
    List<TagModel> tags = new List<TagModel>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dtTag.Rows)
    {
        TagModel tag1 = new TagModel();
        tag1.ID = int.Parse(row["ID"].ToString());
        tag1.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
        query = "select [ID],[Title],[DateTime],[Body] from Posts inner join PostsTag on ID = PostID AND TagID =" + tag1.ID;
        // here I will need to fill tag1.Posts and after that post.tags and so on
        tags.Add(tag1);
    }
    post.Tags = tags;
}
```

Note: I know it is easier to this with entity framework but my teachers requirement is to use manual sql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just keep the list on either Post or Tag, whichever you will be working with as the primary. I would think Post w/ a list of Tags (although that may reverse depending on use case).

On a side note, you should use parameterized sql. It's best to never directly add parameters to sql because of risk sql injection attacks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: So I Should remove List of posts from TagModel? but then how will I keep the list of posts having tagName='even'?

Comment: Ok so your suggestion works for the time being. What I did was instead of getting tag.Posts I created a temp list of tags and populated it with the posts with tag 'even' and instead of returing tags I returned posts